# Problem while rendering time from django datetime field in html input tag

Tags: python, html, django

I want to render datetime fields time value in html time field but when I pass the value to it , it does not show but in the value only it comes.

here is my template

```
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  
                    <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Deadline Time:</label>
                    <input required type="time" name="deadlinetime" value="{{list.deadline.time}}" class="form-control" />
                </div>
```

[image]

In the value it shows but not in the field

Please help me..

Comment: `it does not show but in the value only it comes` means ? Please explain a little bit. You just want to render that in your template ?

Comment: can you show your views.py file code, so that I can know what you are sending

Comment: I have added a picture . So I think you will understand , what I am trying to say